# Are both [Poetic] and [Poetry] needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[poetic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetic) has 17 question and no wiki. [poetry](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) has 176 questions and a wiki.

Should the former be merged into the latter? Should the former be blacklisted to avoid misuse in the future or just make them synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

The posts marked [poetic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetic) seem to consist of posts about poetic language but not (classical or formal) poetry. The highest-voted [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160467/what-is-the-aerial-equivalent-of-bathing-when-one-enjoys-the-breeze) under that tag asks for a poetic term for enjoying the breeze.

While it is accurate to say that *poetry* is simply the noun form of *poetic*, the term *poetry* has acquired enough of a distinctive meaning that it is a little uncomfortable to call flowery or vivid prose *poetry*. Describing it as *poetic* still seems appropriate, maybe in the sense that even though it isn't poetry, it is *like* poetry.

I think there is a place for the two tags to have separate identities. For clarity, I'd suggest renaming [poetic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetic) to `poetic prose`.

Comment: Then info on the [poetic] has to be added since it's empty. Perhaps also add a usage clause: "Use this tag for...".

Comment: FYI, we have at least [one question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280854) about [prose poetry](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/text/poetic-form-prose-poem), but leaving that aside, there may some grey areas around [tag:poetic], [tag:literary-english] and [tag:literature]. Some of the word requests might be more about [tag:obscure-terms] or [tag:rare-words] than poetic or [tag:figurative] vocabulary and constructions.